# Multiple API calls in dotnet core

Tags: c#, api, email, .net-core, sms

I am using dotnet core c#. Here i need to call multiple API's based on which I have send email or SMS. PFB the structure.

```
function SendEmailOrSMS(){
    List user = new List;
    callAPI1(userid) --> to get email id or phone number
    callAPI2(response of API 1) --> to trigger sms
    UpdateResponse() --> DB function
}
```

For every user I have to call this method's and API to trigger SMS or email.
Now for 1000 user it takes 15 mins. I need to trigger for 3.5 mil users .

If I go with 1000 user it takes almost a month to trigger email or SMS where in I need to trigger in a day.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us what PFB is?

Comment: Please find below

Comment: You should probably check if the API you're using has a bulk method you can use. Otherwise you should submit multiple requests in parallel, taking into account any usage or rate limits for the API.

Comment: How to submit multiple request in parallel

Comment: How do you submit the current requests?

Comment: In series the request are submitted

Comment: You'll be having a request throttled later with that many requests.

Answer (score -1):

Does API1 or API2 expose a method for batch processing? If so, you won't need to call it *n* times, but only once (or multiple times, but still not *n* times).

Regardless, this processing can be done in parallel in different threads. This can be achieved by using the `Parallel.ForEach()` method, or by managing the `Task`s by yourself. (The latter is a trickier approach, but can be more customizable.) This way, multiple users could be processed at the same time, so the processing time would decrease a lot.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28442378)

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell: Why doesn’t it offer an answer? It’s pretty high level, but so is the question. If the question requires more detail it should be flagged. But this offers appropriate direction.